# Solution for $y(x^2+y^2)dx + x(3x^2-5y^2)dy = 0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am teaching assistant of an elementary course of ODE and a student asked me to solve the following equation:

$$y(x^2+y^2)dx + x(3x^2-5y^2)dy = 0$$

The standard procedure to solve it consists in multiplying the equation by some function $\mu = \mu(x,y)$. Once we do this we must solve
$$-8\mu(x,y)\cdot (x^2-y^2) +\partial_y\mu(x,y)\cdot \left(yx^2 + y^3\right) - \partial_x\mu(x,y)\left(3x^3-5xy^2\right) = 0.$$
In general one assumes that $\mu$ is constant in one of each variable, but this can not be the case here.

I tried lots of manipulations, but could not handle it. I do appreciate any hints.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5Bx%5D%28x%5E2%2By%5Bx%5D%5E2%29y%27%28x%29+%2B+x%283x%5E2-5y%5Bx%5D%5E2%29+%3D+0) solves it, not sure if it is helpful.

Comment: @Atbey, it helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [First Order homogenous ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions) (observe that all monomials have the same degree -exactly 3-). So the substitution $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ will work.

Indeed, your ODE is $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(x^2+y^2)}{x(5y^2-3x^2)} $$ by dividing each part by $x^3$ (remember the degree of all monomials), you get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y/x-(y/x)^3}{5(y/x)^2-3}$$
Now, the substitution $u=y/x$ or equivalently $y(x)=xu(x)$, whence $\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$. So
$$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u-u^3}{5u^2-3}
$$
and you can separate variables to solve it.

Comment: Indeed, it was clear after seeing the plot on Wolfram, what intrigues me is that the solution is request to use ``integrant factors'' (I don't know if I am translating properly this term). Thanks.

Comment: OH! so maybe you can do a sort of "reverse engineering" to obtain a proper "integrant factor"

Comment: I shall do it! Thank you!

Comment: by the way, I mistranslated, it seems that the correct term is ``integrating factor''

Answer (score 3):

$$y(x^2+y^2)dx + x(3x^2-5y^2)dy = 0$$
Multiply by $y^2$:
$$y^3x^2dx+y^5dx + x^3dy^3-xdy^5 = 0$$
$$(y^3x^2dx + x^3dy^3)+(y^5dx-xdy^5) = 0$$
Divide by $x^2$:
$$y^3dx + xdy^3-d\left (\dfrac {y^5}x \right) = 0$$
$$d(xy^3)-d\left (\dfrac {y^5}x \right) = 0$$
Integrate:
$$xy^3-\dfrac {y^5}x = K$$